# Is there any way to kick off a very specific cron process in Magento 2 using command line?

Tags: magento2, cron, magento-cron

We're working on troubleshooting a bug where product back in stock alerts aren't sent on our production or staging environment, but they are in dev(after a custom patch was applied to all three). Magento 2 by default only schedules this process once a day, even if you change the time the cron is supposed to run. We've cloned our staging environment to run some tests. We'd like to test this more frequently without the need to install one of the cron scheduler apps.

Is there any way to fire off a specific cron process, `catalog_product_alert` in our case, through command line alone?

We're on Magento 2.3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2 Can run specific cron jobs
2. Module https://github.com/Ethan3600/magento2-CronjobManager Might be useful

Comment: I ended up finding this through a colleague yesterday. I was on my way back over to answer the question but you beat me to it. This worked perfectly, thank you!